# Angular 5 Server-side rendering in country subfolders

Tags: angular, internationalization, angular-universal, angular-i18n

I have successfully implemented server side rendering on my angular 5 app thanks to the [universal starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter).

I am now stuck with angular native internationalisation. I can successfully 
`ng build --locale=fr --ouput-path=dist/fr --base-href=fr` without universal rendering.

How can I mix internationalisation with universal rendering?

I can create language folders in server/browser via

`ng build --prod --locale=fr --i18n-file src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --base-href=/fr --deploy-url=/fr --output-path=dist/browser/fr`

`ng build --prod --locale=fr --i18n-file src/locale/messages.fr.xlf --base-href=/fr --deploy-url=/fr --output-path=dist/server/fr --app 1 --output-hashing=false`

And my dist folder looks like:

...dist

.....bowser

........ en

........ fr

.....server

........ en

........ fr

How could I make the [server.ts](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/master/server.ts) serve all languages based on url base?

Hope someone can help!

Many thanks

Comment: do you found the answer. I'm facing the exact same problem :(. Thanks

Comment: Hey, I ended up using the following:
https://github.com/wishrd/angular-universal-i18n-starter

Hope it helps!